# BMW 320D E46 Facelift

Tags: maintenance, bmw, mercedes-benz, repair

I`m about to get a **BMW 320D E46** Face lift model **(2000)** and that is **120K** driven. I would like to hear whether its worth in terms of repairs, maintenance cost ? Do I need to go each and every garage for its maintenance ?

Please provide me common repairs I need to undergo ? In terms of quality of reliability what would be your suggestion ? **Mercedes C180 (2000) **or** **BMW 320D (2000)** model** ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As it stands this question isn't a good fit for the site and will likely be put on hold because the answers will be mainly based on opinion rather than facts. Plus the Merc guys will say don't buy BMW, the BMW guys will say don't buy Mercedes, etc. etc.

Comment: Doing that kind of price quoting is impossible  BUT, if you change your question to  **What kind of maintenance should be performed on a BMW 320D E46 at 120K?** you can then take that info to shops and ask them what they would charge.  That's how I would do it at least.   :-)   Change the question and ask again.